# Some books write Coulomb force is medium independent and some write it is medium dependent why so?

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law, polarization, dielectric, coulombs-law

Some authors say coulomb force is medium independent others say it is medium dependent. I know value of universal gravitational constant does not depend on medium. But value of permittivity does depend on medium. Then why should we not say that coulombs law states that electrostatic force between two charges is:

1. Directly proportional to product of the two charges
2. Inversely proportional to square of separation
3. inversely proportional to permittivity of medium.

Then only it seems to depend on nature of medium.

On other hand if we say original force between the two charges is same whatever is the medium. Change of medium only changes the net force as some additional forces due to polarization get involved .Then saying coulomb force is medium independent seems really true and seems to talk of the original forces between the original two charges.
Also what i feel suppose we bring a third mass in between two masses then the net gravitational force acting on the original masses would surely change on this ground we can say then gravitational force between two masses also depend on intervening medium. But if we are talking of original gravitational force between the two masses and not of new net gravitational force acting on each mass then surely gravitational force is independent of intervening medium.
So what should we say? Is coulomb force medium  dependent or medium independent?

Comment: Can we have some examples of such authors?

Answer (score 3):

As often, if the point of view changes, the meaning of terms changes as well.

If you look at the "medium" macroscopically, i.e. without knowing about the polarization of individual atoms and hence, their contribution to the so-called "permittivity" in matter, you must come to the conclusion that the macroscopic shape/strength of the electric field is influenced by that apparent "permittivity" compared to vacuum. The respective electrostatic Maxwell equations are:
$$\vec\nabla\cdot \vec D = \vec\nabla (\epsilon \vec E)= \rho$$
$$\vec\nabla\times\vec E=0$$
This remains especially true if a charge is surrounded by an infinite medium. So from the point of view of macroscopic electrodynamics, it is true that the apparent permittivity of matter influences the field, i.e. Coulomb's law is **medium-dependent**.

But if you look at the medium from the microscopic point of view, you see that the displacement field $\vec D$ that previously entered the macroscopic Maxwell's equations is nothing but a quantity, that accounts for the polarization of lots of individual atoms in a very averaged way. Gauss' law from the macroscopic Maxwell equations can then be written with $\vec D=\epsilon_0\vec E+\vec P$ as
$$\epsilon_0\vec\nabla\cdot \vec E+ \vec\nabla\cdot\vec P= \rho$$
or equivalently
$$\vec\nabla\cdot \vec E = \frac{1}{\epsilon_0}(\rho-\vec\nabla\cdot\vec P)=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}(\rho+\rho_{medium})=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\rho_{total}$$

So what previously appeard as a macroscopic permittivity (leading to macroscopic polarization of a "medium") can be more accurately described as an external electric field generated be a huge number of positive and negative charges (which additionally obey the laws of quantum mechanics). From this point of view, this huge number of charges relates to a single charge that is embedded among them, and which generates a Coulomb field, in no different way than another single charge relates to the charge that generates the Coulomb field in question. Does a second charge influence the Coulomb field of the first one? No, not in common parlance, because the resulting total field strength, although it is the linear superposition of the individual Coulomb fields of these two charges, doesn't change the two addends in this sum itself. So from the point of view of microscopic electrodynamics, the charges contained in matter are no different than the charge whose Coulomb field is examined, nameley they all have a Coulomb field themselves, and all of these just add up to the total field strength. Therefore, in this context, the Coulomb field is **medium independent**.

If you read all this, you will notice that it is just rephrasing what you have already written in your question. You have basically answered your own question. It just depends of the context, macroscopic or microscopic.

Comment: Your answer addresses the question! You might consider saying a little more about polarization.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for because  Seares Zemansky has used the word "net force " on each will change . So I guessed that original forces amoung them wont change and Coulombs law talks of original mutal forces and not of what net force a charge would feel.

Answer (score 0):

Coulomb's Law is often (conveniently) written as $F= k \dfrac{Q_1Q_2}{r^2}$, but the key is to note that $$k=\dfrac1{4\pi\epsilon}$$ where $\epsilon$ is the permittivity of the medium you're in.  So that's where your medium dependence comes from.

Comment: But when some books give statement of coulombs law there is only sign of proportionality ...no equality sign with k introduced. Then doesn't it seem the Statement for this law is incomplete.

Comment: @SheenSha most times you work in the same medium, namely free space

Comment: But we see it has been made clear that F=ma is for inertial frame. But after giving this statement of coulombs law no book writes it is valied when you work only in a particular medium.

Comment: it;s valid in any medium, you just have to use the right $\epsilon$

Answer (score 0):

It may come from certain conventions: namely, [Gaussian units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units) or [ESU-CGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centimetre%E2%80%93gram%E2%80%93second_system_of_units#Various_extensions_of_the_CGS_system_to_electromagnetism) drop the respective constants and shuffle the permittivity into charges, expressed in [statC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statcoulomb). There exists an argument to favor CGS over SI for electromagnetism - precisely to drop the "arbitrary" $\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}$ in the Coulomb's law. So it might be that these books confusing you (and many physics students) have to do with that school of thought/tradition: after all, to someone who already knows physics well, it does not incur that much difficulty navigating these systems and may be beneficial to not drag these bulky coefficients throughout all the calculations, similar to how ["natural"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units) units are defined differently in different areas of physics.

Answer (score 0):

In the universal law of gravitation, we say that any two-point masses exert a force on each other which goes as F = Gm1m2/r2
where G is the universal constant of gravitation.

Similarly, in Coulomb’s law of electrostatics, we write the force between two point charges asF = kq1q2/r2 where k is a constant of proportionality. In SI units, k is taken as 1/4πε where ε is the permittivity of the medium. Also in magnetism, we get another constant, which in SI units, is taken as µ/4π where µ is the permeability of the medium.
Although G, ε, and µ arise as proportionality constants, there is a difference between gravitational force and electromagnetic force. While the gravitational force does not depend on the intervening medium, the electromagnetic force depends on the medium between the two charges or magnets. Hence, while G is a universal constant, ε and µ depend on the medium.

Hope this answer does justice to your question!!